# New design: why don’t we use the maximum screen size?

Tags: feature-request, design

I know that the new responsive design follows some important design rules. However, I have now a lot of blank spaces everywhere:

[image: Screenshot of a question — to the left and right there’s lots of whitespace]

Disabling two `max-width` rules gives the following result:

[image: Suggested design — the content panel has responsive width so that the sidebars fill the whitespace on both sides]

I think that Stack Overflow users are quite educated: they should be able to decide between using an easy-to-read or a best-fit layout.

The second output missed some little margins. But even if it can be too large for comfortable reading, at least I have more content. And the default of 728px for content is really small to me.

Comment: No thanks, reading lines of texts that long are incredible taxing.

Comment: @ivarni I *know* that. Of course it is difficult, the human eye is used to scroll vertically, not horizontally, etc. But there is a lot of reason for using it. StackOverflow is not a journalistic web site with long articles. And sometimes, I just skipped a lot of text.

Comment: What screen resolution do you have? For me, the blank space has always been there and I'm confused as to why so many people are saying it's new.

Comment: This isn't *for* SO, it's for the entire network, many sites of which **do** tend towards long articles.